# Using Dynamics 2013 Sdk.Soap.js to ExecuteMultiple requests from a Web Resource (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, soap, dynamics-crm

Does anyone know of or have a working example of calling Dynamics CRM 2013 SOAP ExecuteMultiple from jQuery in Web Resource? I'm using Sdk.Soap.js and Sdk.ExecuteMultiple.js. I need to update around 50 records at a time. I've only found C# versions and one non-working js version of ExecuteMultiple. The samples don't seem to address ExecuteMultiple.

Thanks in advance for your assistance,
KMT

Answer (score 1):

This is a test function I've verified works:

```
function executeMultipleSample() {
Sdk.jQ.setJQueryVariable($);

var account1 = new Sdk.Account();
account1.Name.setValue("Account 1");
var account2 = new Sdk.Account();
account2.Name.setValue("Account 2");
var account3 = new Sdk.Account();
account3.Name.setValue("Account 3");

var createRequests = new Sdk.Collection(Sdk.OrganizationRequest);
createRequests.add(new Sdk.CreateRequest(account1));
createRequests.add(new Sdk.CreateRequest(account2));
createRequests.add(new Sdk.CreateRequest(account3));

var emSettings = new Sdk.ExecuteMultipleSettings(true,true);

var req = new Sdk.ExecuteMultipleRequest(createRequests, emSettings);

Sdk.jQ.execute(req)
.done(function (resp) {
var responses = resp.getResponses();
responses.forEach(function (responseItem) {
var id = responseItem.getResponse().getId();
console.log(id);
})
})
.fail(function (error) {
console.log(e.message);
});
}
```

Several different objects in play here. You get a collection of Sdk.ExecuteMultipleResponseItem returned, so you must get the response out of it. If there is no response, you the getFault method to find out what went wrong.

The JavaScript code above is similar to the C# sample here [Sample: Execute multiple requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863604.aspx) so if you can do in C# it should be similar in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SoapLogger to generate [Soap Xml](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/05/23/microsoft-dynamics-crm-soap-logger-a-tool-that-can-greatly-simplify-writing-http-requests/) for a request.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the source of Sdk.Soap.js.

Constructor: `Sdk.ExecuteMultipleRequest(requests, settings)` where `requests` is a `Sdk.Collection` of type `Sdk.OrganizationRequest` and `settings` is of type `Sdk.ExecuteMultipleSettings`. Both are optional, but I would at least use the `requests` parameter.

I imagine you have an Array of `Sdk.OrganizationRequest` to perform multiple requests at once, in that case your code would be like the following:

```js
var executeMultipleResponse =
    Sdk.jQ.execute(
        new Sdk.ExecuteMultipleRequest(
            new Sdk.Collection(Sdk.OrganizationRequest, arrayOfRequests)));
```